# Laravel pivot consultation

Tags: php, laravel

I need advice about my model relationships,

## Logic

1. `Group` has many `users`
2. `Group` has many `admins`
3. `User` has many `groups` (as user)
4. `User` has many `groups` (as admin)

## Database Structure

1. Group Table
2. User Table
3. Group_Users table (save id of user and id of group)
4. Group_Admins table (save id of user and id of group)

## Relationship Code

`User model`

```
public function groupsUser() {
    return $this->hasMany(GroupUser::class);
}

public function groupsAdmin() {
    return $this->hasMany(GroupAdmin::class);
}
```

`Group model`

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany(GroupUser::class);
}

public function admins() {
    return $this->hasMany(GroupAdmin::class);
}
```

`GroupUser model`

```
public function group() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

`GroupAdmin model`

```
public function group() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

## Help wanted

Basically as the relationships between `users` and `groups` is **many to many** normally I shouldn't need models of `GroupUser` and `GroupAdmin` and then just using `sync()` function in order to add/remove users and group id's from those tables.

**What is my concerns then?**

Normally I use that type of connection when I want input bulk ids into database (let say adding tags to posts, suddenly relate 10 tags id to 1 post) that moment using `sync()` and removing `GroupUser` and `GroupAdmin` models makes sense but in my case as users joins/adds to groups one by one, **what do you suggest for this relationships?**

1. Is my current approach makes sense?
2. Is is better if I remove those `GroupUser` and `GroupAdmin` models and add them to `user, group` model like:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'group_users', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

and such so?

What do you think is the best practice?

Comment: What you have described here, groups <-> users is ok to be many to many. But you should relate user hasMany admins and admin belongsToUser instead having relation between admins and groups. Just thought about those relations.

Comment: @Tpojka user has many admin?! user is admin, group has many admins.

Comment: Usually, I used Spatie (or sometimes laratrust) permissions and didn't need admins table. It is not known from questions what are groups or if admin is part of group. This way written is very ambiguous and group can be something like (biology, chemistry, physics...) but also can be something like (admin, moderator, editor, lector...) to try to explain my doubts in plastic way. In first case it is entity and in second it's a role. We don't know actually what is group there.

Comment: @Tpojka it's not actually sort of role and permission things to use those packages, it's chatting app like any other. group users(members) can chat, group admins can moderate group info. simple as that

Answer (score 0):

> users and groups is many to many

your tables like this?

`users`, `user_group` , `groups` ?

How about use 'belongsToMany' relation?
[Laravel many to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

```php
// User model

public function groups() {
    return $this->belognsToMany(Group::class);
}
```

```php
// Group model

public function users() {
    return $this->belognsToMany(User::class);
}
```

And use like.

```php
User::find(1)->groups; // return user 1 groups
User::find(1)->groups()->sync($groupIds); // relate user and groups

Group::find(1)->users; // return group 1 users
```

If you have role column in your users table, you cold add relation like.

```php
// Group model

public function users() {
    return $this->belognsToMany(User::class)->where('role', 'the role of normal user');
}

public function admins() {
    return $this->belognsToMany(User::class)->where('role', 'the role of admin user');
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my relationships to your suggestions, let me try add/remove data and see if all works then I get back to you.